# Elastic search - one index vs multiple indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on a solution to store application logs in Elastic Search for many applications across many development teams. The structure of each log entry is identical with an "app" field to indicate the application.

The #1 goal is to support efficient querying within a single "app". Querying across all apps, while still important, would be secondary.

I'm trying to determine what is best:

EDIT: in both cases I will use time-based indexes.

**multiple index series**

Each "app" would have a series of time-based indexes (app1-2017-04-01,app1-2017-04-02,... etc.) The user would perform searches directly against these smaller indexes. The thought here is that since the indexes are smaller in size, maybe querying against them is faster?

**single index series**

Use one giant index series to represent all application logs (e.g. logs-2017-04-01, logs-2017-04-02, ... etc) Users would query the "app" field to narrow their search results.

**Which is faster in this case? I'm curious about the overhead cost of additional indexes**

Comment: When dealing with logging, you really want to use time-based indexes. The way I'd do it would be to have each app write to its own monthly index (appname__2017-06, anotherapp__2017-06, etc). This way when the time comes to delete old data, you can drop the entire month instead of running expensive and slow delete queries.

Comment: @Johnny currently I am writing daily time based indexes per app. My question is whether I should use one giant time based index or many smaller time based indexes

Comment: You are approaching this from the wrong angle. You should ask yourself a different set of questions. What's the retention period? How many apps there are? How much data per app (in GBs) per day you predict you'll have? How many ES nodes? What are the hardware resources of these nodes? Are you primarily querying latest period's indices or older indices have an equal amount of queries as well?

Answer (score 48):

In most cases multiple indexes are better:

1. Searching against smaller dataset is faster
2. You are less limited in mapping structure. If you need to change it for new data, you can keep old data without reindexing and just put new mapping for new index
3. It's more scalable and flexible. You can keep old indexes on a different hard drive or a different machine.
4. You still can search against multiple indexes, if required.
5. The overhead for index is small. If you have lots of documents per index, documents take much more space than index metadata. If not, you can take a smaller time period to split your log indexes

Comment: How do we filter data with multiple indexes?

Answer (score 10):

I will provide hypothetical guidance, since you chose to ignore answers to my questions.

When it comes to a logging use case (time based indices) it is imperative to have at hand some data about future plans: for how long you want to keep the logging data around (retention period), what will be the usage pattern for the collected data (queries frequency, indexing frequency), how much data there will be each day (referring here to data on disk aka shard size). Before thinking at the issue of "per-app-index" or "single-index" do consider the advices below. After you do the math regarding the shards sizes, how many there will be for the chosen retention period, then you can think about per-app or single index.

Depending on the shards sizes especially and the retention period secondly, one would need to consider if the time-based indices will be daily, weekly or monthly. A good rule-of-thumb for the size of a shard is maximum 30-50GB, everything above this would make any recovery, shards relocation, searching potentially slower and potentially affecting the cluster stability.

If your apps are capable of generating large amounts of data daily that would go over the number mentioned above, one shouldn't choose to make the indices per application. If the sizes are smaller, then again it depends. A huge number of shards on one node is wasting resources and would make searching slow. Each shards has a fixed set of memory that is being used just because it exists. Also, when performing searches each shard will perform its search by one thread. One thread is *basically* one CPU core. The higher the time span being used in searches (more indices being searched), the higher number of concurrent searches happening, the higher the context switching at OS level between multiple threads trying to use the CPU cores. All in all, don't try to squeeze in a single node hundreds of shards, **unless** only some of them will be used at any given time. If you plan on querying all the data in your cluster most of the time, the number of shards you'd want to have on each node shrinks drastically. Otherwise your cluster will not be able to keep up with the load.

If your logging use case is the one which **mostly** has high activity on the most recent data (last few days to one week) then consider the approach of hot-warm architecture: https://www.elastic.co/blog/hot-warm-architecture-in-elasticsearch-5-x

The exercise of building and configuring a cluster does always involve testing. So, do please try to test the performance of your queries on a piece of data that's as much as possible identical to real life data. Also, do this on one node that has the hardware specs of the nodes in the production cluster.

Answer (score 8):

In terms of performance is better to use a large index than several small indices, as you can see on the article **Index vs. Type** by **Adrien Grand**.

> An index is stored in a set of shards, which are themselves Lucene
>   indices. This already gives you a glimpse of the limits of using a new
>   index all the time: Lucene indices have a small yet fixed overhead in
>   terms of disk space, memory usage and file descriptors used. For that
>   reason, a single large index is more efficient than several small
>   indices: the fixed cost of the Lucene index is better amortized across
>   many documents.

My suggestion is to use one time-based-index for all applications where each application is a different type of your index. It will make it easier to you when searching on each application log and so straightforward when searching for all applications at the same time.

For example:

If you want to search in one app only you can use:

`http://yourserver:9200/logs-2017-04-01/app1/_search`

And for all applications:

`http://yourserver:9200/logs-2017-04-01/_search`

Other good point to evaluate is that each application can have different number of log entries. This way if you have one different index for each app it will be so difficult when sizing your shards for each one. For that reason, the use of only one index will make it easier to you when sizing your cluster. If the index is too large just split it in more shards.

Comment: "Searching 1 index of 50 shards is exactly equivalent to searching 50 indices with 1 shard each: both search requests hit 50 shards." ([source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multiple-indices.html)). The point: in terms of performance, indexes don't matter that much, shards do. Having shards containing logs from different apps is less performant if your queries always hit one app at the same time, which is the OP's #1 goal.

Comment: When talking about performance you don't need to think only in number of queries but in how the Lucene indices will use your resources. Each index will be a different Lucene index that means you need to think about disk space, memory usage and file descriptors used by each index.

Comment: That's a fair point, but I don't agree that is the most relevant in this case (how many apps should there be to make it relevant...). Shards are the units that allow you to actually scale out your cluster to gain performance. But besides that, mixing app logs means that Elasticsearch will have to search through *every* shard on each query, even though the user may be only searching for logs of an specific app.

Comment: I agree with @BrunodosSantos. And, as I said in the comments of the initial post, the questions the poster is asking are wrong. The same goes with the other two answers to this post: they are wrong. I see every day users pushing the resources boundaries of their clusters because they don't consider retention period, size of the indices, resources at their disposal etc. They don't properly test before going into production and then they complain about performance...

Comment: The answer to any engineering problem is almost always "it depends". So saying that answers are "wrong" seems pretty radical to me. You're asking important questions (available resources, data volume, etc) but they're not necessarly relevant: if you don't have the resources then **any** answer is wrong. We're implicitly assuming here this it's not the case. Further performance tuning techniques could be applied as well (Hot-Warm architecture, deleting old logs, etc) but again, it's not relevant to mention them under the circunstances. Vague answers are not very useful.

Comment: @federicojasson if you don't size the cluster properly and build your indices properly, the issue everyone is focusing on now will be a void discussion. And the way you configure your indices (based on their size on disk, daily/weekly/monthly etc) will matter. If you go with indices per application without thinking about the size of those indices you can end up having 1000s of shards on each node and waste hardware resources in vain. These kind of tuning scenarios are difficult and I agree that "it depends", but before jumping to indices per app or not, other things need to be considered.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I agree with you. I just think it's more likely to have a few apps with lots of logs, than lots of apps with just a few logs. The latter case would be the one resulting in a lot of shards. But yes, I recognize it's a feasible and it deserves to be considered as a possibility.

Comment: @BrunodosSantos BTW, I've just read the mentioned [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type), and it clearly states that using multiplex indexes i'ts a good alternative in most cases: *"[...] types are useful because they can help reduce the number of Lucene indices [...]. But there is another way [...]: creating indices that have fewer shards. [...] instead of folding 5 types into the same index, you could create 5 indices with 1 primary shard each. [...] the overhead of Lucene indices will be easily amortized. [...] there are not as many use cases for types as you expected."*

Comment: @federicojasson In most of real cases you don't want to manage different indices for each application. It makes your architecture difficult to maintain. Other point is that in lots of times you can't predict how many log entries you will have for each application. Sometimes one application starts with a bit entries and becomes complex and complex. In lots of real cases you don't expect to make changes in your "app index" all the time your application grows. But if you have an environment with predictable log entries and few number of application your approach can be a possibility.

Answer (score 6):

Keeping different indexes for different apps gives you flexibility and can, eventually, help you to improve performance by tuning the number of shards/replicas for each app. In any case, you can always allow cross searches by defining aliases or simply by using wildcards.

Considering that multiple teams will access the data, keeping different indexes for different apps is also clearer. Finally, if you eventually want to add some sort of access control (using Shield/X-Pack), having different indexes will definitely make things easier.

Comment: Now they have removed the [mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html) and I think your answer was in the essence of how lucene works

Comment: How can we filter on multiple indexes?

Comment: I'm a bit outdated with ES (this is an old answer). But seems you can still add indexes to an alias, and then query that alias: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html